# WPF ListView How to select a item from List<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, selecteditem

I have a `Listview` where the datasource is a `List<T>` , when the content of the `List<T>` had changed I have to refresh the `Listview` and after that select the item I was selected before to refresh the `Listview`. This is my code that is not working well.

```
if (cbGroups.SelectedIndex!=-1)
{
    _GroupSelected = (Groups)cbGroups.SelectedValue;
}

_ItemSource = true;

// Refresh data source with the new records readed.

cbGroups.ItemsSource = Groups_DB.Records;

_ItemSource = false;

if (cbGroups.Items.Count >= 0 && _GroupSelected != null)
{
    _ItemSource = true;
    cbGroups.SelectedValue = _GroupSelected;
    int x = cbGroups.Items.IndexOf(_GroupSelected); // x is always -1
    _ItemSource = false;
}
```

So, someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems obvious that the old `_GroupSelected` item is not an element of the new `ItemsSource` collection.

Take a look at how the properties `SelectValue` and `SelectedValuePath` work together. Then restore the selection by using an appropriate "key" property as `SelectedValue`.

Assuming a record has a unique `Id` property, set

```
<ListView x:Name="cbGroups" SelectedValuePath="Id" ...>
```

with code behind like this:

```
var selectedId = cbGroups.SelectedValue;
cbGroups.ItemsSource = Groups_DB.Records;
cbGroups.SelectedValue = selectedId;
```